# JavaFx application from netBeans: How to include external jar or class path jars in build?

Tags: jar, classpath, javafx-2, netbeans-7

I have made on Javafx 2 **standalone application** using netbeans 7.2 IDE. Internally netbeans use ant script for making a build.

Now my application creates some XML file based on some input. For xml creation I have used one third party jar file 'xstream-1.4.3.jar'. Now when I make build and run the application from netbeans IDE only.. application works fine. But when I copy jar to some other location my application stops working.

Reason being when jar file is copied to some other location, application is not able to find 'xstream**.jar' file. ***So now how to include this jar file (all jar files from class path) in the build*** so that my application can become distributable.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

*The manifest file in the JAR is updated to include entries that designate main class and any libraries that are on the project's classpath.*

http://netbeans.org/kb/docs/java/javase-deploy.html#build

Answer (score 0):

Include the following code in your build.xml file and change the folder names to suit your project.

```
 <target name="-post-jar">   
   <jar jarfile="${dist.jar}" update="true">   
     <zipfileset src="C:/Java/ExcelJars/jxl.jar" includes="**/*.class" />   
     <zipfileset src="C:/Java/ExcelJars/SX.jar" includes="**/*.class"/> 
   </jar>   
 </target>
```